# How to stop spinner loader after loading in Laravel and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I use this code to inset a spinner loader using jquery inside my Laravel project. 
The code is working, but the spinner isn't distroyed after page loading. 
How to be sure to stop this jquery after my page is totally loaded ?

This is the Spinner Code

```
 <script>
   var loading = new Loading({
    direction: 'ver',
      title: 'Loading',
      titleColor: '#FFF',
      titleFontSize: 14,
      animationIn: 'animated fadeIn',
      animationOut: 'animated fadeOut',
      animationDuration:  5,
   });
  </script>
```

My project stucture blades are like that : 
A main page named App.blade.php , with

```
 @yield('content')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `load` event to stop it:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  loading = false; //just destroy the object completely
});
```

You could also use `DOMContentLoaded` in place of `load`. They're similar, but not the same, from the MDN:

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

[Load is a bit more complex, read about the chain here to get a better understanding](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop)